# Leave connection as soon as served in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

In my project, one subdomain handles a process that takes a **huge amount** of data into the memory so I want to close the connection immediately after serving the result to the user.
I think NGINX KeepAlive timeout can handle this situation. So is there any possibility to give min KeepAliveTimeout for a particular subdomain only?
or Is there any other possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout), `keepalive_timeout` can be used in `server` and even in `location` contexts, to did you try to specifiy this parameter in the `server` block for your subdomain? Also, try to set `keepalive_requests`  to 1.